# Set the value of an input field inside a form with a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below html. I need a jquery selector to set the value of the hidden attribute (SelectedEntityID) inside the form with the following attribute (data-ajax="true"):

```
    <form  action="/myServer/List/ToolbarFunction" method="post">
    <input name="SelectedEntityID" id="SelectedEntityID" type="hidden" value="">
    </form>

    <form  action="/myServer/List/AjaxToolbarFunction" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="SuccessMessage" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-failure="FailMessage">
    <input name="SelectedEntityID" id="SelectedEntityID" type="hidden" value="">
    </form>
```

*Notes:
I need the input element (SelectedEntityID) to be inside the two forms and have the same ID.*

I have tried the following:

```
$("form[data-ajax='true'] #SelectedEntityID").val('123')
```

but the value is not set and there arre no errors in the browser console.

Comment: Why do you have form fields with same id?

Comment: your selector is looking for the attribute in the form tag, which doesn't exist. `$("form #SelectedEntityID[data-ajax='true']")` is what you are looking for. However note that no two html elements should share the same id attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique in page. You can use `name` to select the element

```
$("form[data-ajax='true'] input[name='SelectedEntityID']").val('123')
```